# django-auth-ldap "an integer is required" error

Tags: django, django-authentication

Using Django 1.4 and django-auth-ldap 1.1, I'm trying to configure my web app to authenticate users against an LDAP service. On supplying the correct login credentials in the login form, I'm getting this error :-

> TypeError at /login/
>
> an integer is required
>
> Request Method:    POST
>
> Request URL:   http://mydomain.com:8000/login/
>
> Django Version:    1.4
>
> Exception Type:    TypeError
>
> Exception Value:
>
> an integer is required
>
> Exception Location:    /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ldap/functions.py in _ldap_function_call, line 57
> Python Executable:     /usr/bin/python
>
> Python Version:    2.6.5
>
> ....Python Path information

Why is this error happening ?

Here is the pasted trace info :-

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/login/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'myapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,  **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in wrapper
  69.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in login
  36.         if form.is_valid():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  124.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  115.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  271.         self._clean_form()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  299.             self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  167.                                            password=password)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  43.     for backend in get_backends():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in get_backends
   34.         backends.append(load_backend(backend_path))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in load_backend
  28.     return cls()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap-1.1.1-py2.6.egg/django_auth_ldap/backend.py" in __init__
   93.         self.ldap = self.ldap_module()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap-1.1.1-py2.6.egg/django_auth_ldap/backend.py" in ldap_module
   104.         return _LDAPConfig.get_ldap(options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap-1.1.1-py2.6.egg/django_auth_ldap/config.py" in get_ldap
    74.                 cls.ldap.set_option(opt, value)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ldap/functions.py" in set_option
     124.   _ldap_function_call(_ldap.set_option,option,invalue)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ldap/functions.py" in _ldap_function_call
    57.       result = func(*args,**kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /login/
Exception Value: an integer is required
```

Comment: Need more traceback. The relevant part is probably where the form values are being passed to the ldap package. Something in the form values isn't what it is expecting.

Comment: You need to post your code that is handling user logins.

Comment: Added the traceback information.

Answer (score 0):

Your LDAP server is complaining about one of the key/value pairs in your AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS. Make sure you're using the `ldap.OPT_*` constants as the dictionary keys.